# Why is it not possible to access "dependsOn" and "description" task properties in the same way?

Tags: gradle, groovy

By reading the Gradle documentation I see that both `description` and `dependsOn` are property for the `Task` class.
We can set the `description` property in different ways:

```
task MyTask
MyTask.description("This is MyTask")
MyTask.description "This is MyTask"
MyTask.description = "This is MyTask"
```

But even though `dependsOn` is a property as well, we can only have:

```
task MyTask
task AnotherTask
MyTask.dependsOn(AnotherTask)
MyTask.dependsOn AnotherTask
```

Because it is not possible to use:

```
MyTask.dependsOn = AnotherTask
```

The error is:

> Cannot cast object 'task ':AnotherTask'' with class
>   'org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated' to class 'java.lang.Iterable'

I can't understand what kind of cast is it done behind the scene.
Is it a cast involving only the `=` operator for a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `=` operator to "assign" a value to `dependsOn` property, but you have to provide a valid type:

```
MyTask.dependsOn = [AnotherTask]
```

Otherwise you get `ClassCastException`:

```
> Cannot cast object 'task ':AnotherTask'' with class 'org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated' to class 'java.lang.Iterable'
```

#### Groovy `myTask.x = ...` vs. calling `myTask.setX(...)` method

And this is correct behavior - if you take a look inside `org.gradle.api.Task` interface source code you will find that `description` is not a field but a pair of getter and setter methods:

```
@Internal
String getDescription()

void setDescription(String var1);
```

and the same applies to `dependsOn` "property":

```
@Internal
Set<Object> getDependsOn()

void setDependsOn(Iterable<?> var1)
```

In this case Groovy allows you to access both methods like they were properties but it passes execution to those methods. So when you do:

```
MyTask.description
```

you actually call `MyTask.getDescription()`. And when you do:

```
MyTask.description = 'This is description'
```

you actually call `MyTask.setDescription('This is description')`

#### `MyTask.dependsOn()` case

There is also one thing worth mentioning about `dependsOn` case. As I mentioned earlier `org.gradle.api.Task` interface contains `Set<Object> getDependsOn()` and `void setDependsOn(Iterable<?> var1)`. But that's not all. There is also a method:

```
Task dependsOn(Object... var1);
```

It expects varargs (single argument of type `Object` or array of `Object[]`). In this case you can execute following method calls:

```
MyTask.dependsOn AnotherTask // -> equivalent of MyTask.dependsOn(AnotherTask)
MyTask.dependsOn([AnotherTask] as Object[])
```

but you cannot call:

```
MyTask.dependsOn [AnotherTask]
MyTask.dependsOn [AnotherTask] as Object[] // -> equivalent of (MyTask.dependsOn [AnotherTask]) as Object[]
```

First case wont work, because you need to explicitly cast a collection to `Obejct[]` array. Second one also wont work, because casting to `Object[]` has to be applied to a parameter. Skipping parentheses in this case causes that compiler tries to apply casting to a result of the method and we end up with `ClassCastException` from the first case.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is helpful.
So MyTask.dependsOn = [AnotherTask] is working, as well as MyTask.dependsOn([AnotherTask]).
What is not valid is MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]. How come? If we use the latter notation, are we not respecting the type expected by setDependsOn()?

Comment: @acejazz No, `MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]` is a different story - `Task` interface contains method `Task dependsOn(Object... var1)`. And `MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]` is an equivalent of `MyTask.dependsOn([TaskB])` call because groovy allows you to skip parentheses.  Correct call in this case would be `MyTask.dependsOn([TaskB] as Object[])` because you have to cast `ArrayList` to `Object[]` - compiler wont do it implicitly.

Comment: And because `Task dependsOn(Object... var1)` uses varargs it will work fine with just a single or multiple arguments separated with coma. If you want to pass a list to `Task dependsOn(Object... var1)` you have to explicitly cast to `Object[]`

Comment: I'm getting there, sorry! If, as you say, ```MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]``` is an equivalent of ```MyTask.dependsOn([TaskB])```, why the latter is working and the first one is not? It's like the ```as Object[]``` cast is implicit only in between the parentheses.

Comment: @acejazz Not exactly. If you skip parentheses in this case compiler will apply `as Object[]` cast to a result of `dependsOn` method, just like an equivalent of `(MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]) as Object[]`. It happens because compiler doesn't know your intention - do you want to apply it to a method argument or a method result. You have to be explicit in this case.

Comment: I'll try to be as more precise as possible now, sorry if I haven't been before. What is the difference between ```MyTask.dependsOn [TaskB]``` and ```MyTask.dependsOn([TaskB])```? I don't know Groovy much, so I don't know why one is working and one is not. I hope you will understand my picky doubt.

Comment: @acejazz There is no difference, because parentheses are optional in Groovy in some cases (link: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-optional-parenthesis.html). But in your case - if you want to cast a parameter with `as Object[]` you have to add parentheses to explicitly point which part has to be cast to `Object[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now! :)